# Two actions in one form (and form validation)

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to create a form that will redirect to PayPal after saving to my database in Django app. So my form in html looks like this:

```
<form method="POST" name="form_order" id="form_order">
  <!-- my django field -->
  [...]
  <!-- my hidden PayPal field -->
  <button type="submit" name="purhase" id="purhase" onclick="return SubmitForm();">BUY</button>
</form>
```

Then I create JavaScript code:

```
  <script >
  function SubmitForm()
  {

      document.form_order.action = ''
      document.form_order.target='';
      document.form_order.submit();

      document.form_order.action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
      document.form_order.target='_top';
      document.form_order.submit();
      return true;
  }
  </script>
```

But this does not save the data in the database, and the user is redirected to payment even though the form is not filled out.

So I'm trying to check my form is valid:

```
  <script >
  function SubmitForm()
  {

      document.form_order.action = ''
      document.form_order.target='';
      document.form_order.submit();
      if (("#form_order").valid())
      {
      document.form_order.action='https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
      document.form_order.target='_top';
      document.form_order.submit();
      }
      return true;
  }
  </script>
```

This saves the database if the form is correct but does not perform any action with PayPal (the form validates at the server level). How can I save my form and send user to PayPal only if my database is saved first?

Comment: Hmm if you want to create a two action with a single form then why not try AJAX in Django? but it will be a little bit complicated because you need to pass the CSRF key to ajax.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it is clear, you are calling function `submitForm()` on click of button. Thus,  button click gives preference to javascript code and it does not submit form and before doing form submission, it redirects to paypal site.

Please refer to following link: [html and jquery](https://blog.webnersolutions.com/jquery-and-html5-validations-together). From this link, you will get some direction.

You should use ajax call on click of button. With ajax, you can save information to database and after success of ajax, you should write paypal redirect code.